# OCRA compiled Ruby Watir Webdriver .exe "says it doesnt have a valid url"

Tags: firefox, watir-webdriver, webautomation, ocra

I am compiling a Ruby script as a test to run independent of needing any dependencies, there are two lines of code that are compiled with OCRA --windows abc.rb

The file does not run on other computers, and I cannot discover why.  Any suggestions greatly appreciated.  Here are the two lines:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
@browser = Watir::Browser.new
```

Comment: what browser is installed on those other systems?  as you are not specifying what browser to start, webdriver is going to default to firefox.  If firefox is not on the system, I think you might get an error similar to that..  (although I thought it was a 'unable to obtain stable firefox connection' that you'd see in that instance..

Comment: They have Firefox installed, Thank you for your reply. Today I am going to run additional tests to clarify the exact run error result messages.  May I please share those results with you for your review and reply?

Comment: just edit your original question to incorporate the additional information.  I've never worked with ORCA so I have no idea

Comment: Also if you search a bit you might find some other questions here from folks that use or have used ORCA with watir which might be able to help you